# How can i insert an image in the middle of a doughnut chart in a react project with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is the function for adding image
const textCenter = {
id: "textCenter",
beforeDatasetsDraw(chart:any) {
const {ctx, data} = chart;

```
        ctx.save();
         const image = new Image();      
        image.src = momo;      
        const imageSize = 40;
        ctx.font = 'bolder 30px sans-serif';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.drawImage(image, chart.chart.width / 2 - imageSize / 2, chart.chart.height / 2 - imageSize / 2, imageSize, imageSize);
    }
  }



   <Doughnut
                data={datas}
                options={options}
                width={356}
                height={358}
                plugins={[textCenter]}
              />
```